# why is methane gas solubility in water higher than carbon monoxide solubility in water?

Tags: solubility

[image]

The above graph depicts solubility in water at various temps. 
If we are dissolving in polar water, why is methane more soluble than a polar molecule like carbon monoxide?

Comment: So, given the strong dependence on temperature, this implies that the solubility is driven more by entropic considerations than enthalpic considerations, as the latter should be relatively constant over different temperatures. That means that your question may be flawed in that polarity is not the driving factor of solubility for gases.

Comment: Carbon monoxide is much less polar than it might seem.

Comment: If CO were nonpolar wouldn't it experience greater dispersion forces due to its higher mass relative to methane? My book states that gas solubility should increase with mass.

Comment: Well, it's **molar** solubility so value is already divided by molar mass... Weight percent for CO is higher then for CH4.

Comment: Polarity get trumped by hydrogen bonds?